# Pandas DataFrame Function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have problem to use function for Pandas DataFrame,  only 1st column result calculated.
Problem seem coming out when I extract value from df2, as it was OK when I give direct value to G and H, but I really need to extract from df2 DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def mmInch(x):
    return(x/25.4)
def Inchmm(x):
    return(x*25.4)
def PsiBarg(x):
    return(x/14.5)

def MB31G(L,W,T,S,D,P):
    Z=(mmInch(L))**2/(D*(mmInch(T)))
    M=np.where(Z>50,0.032*0.032*Z+3.3,(1+0.6275*Z-0.003375*Z**2)**(1/2))
    F=P*((1-0.85*W)/(1-0.85*W/M))
    I=2*F*mmInch(T)/D
    return(PsiBarg(I*S))

raw_data = {'L': [2,4,5,6,4], 'W':[0.1,0.12,0.15,0.3,0.4],'T': [12,12,12,15,15], 'S':[0.72,0.72,0.72,0.5,0.5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['L', 'W', 'T', 'S',])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[28], 'b': [75000]})

G=df2['a']
H=df2['b']

df1['Result']=MB31G(df1['L'],df1['W'],df1['T'],df1['S'],G,H)
df1
```

Comment: Do you need single values or value series? `df['a']` will return series. One element long, but still series.

Comment: I need singe value extracted from series

Comment: do you need `G=df2.loc[0, 'a']` and `H=df2.loc[0, 'b']`?

Comment: Ups...yes, It works on real one